# Django CustomUser deploying and getting error: relation "accounts_customuser" does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am deploying my django to VSP using Dokku.  I have the project working on my local computer but when I deploy to dokku, I'm getting errors when it tries to do the migrations.  The dokku is deployed with `git push dokku main:master` and migrations are in my `.gitignore`, so migrations on my local computer are not being pushed.  I am using a `CustomUser` model which extends `AbstractUser`.

The problem looks to be `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_customuser" does not exist`.

**full logs/trace**

```
PS C:\> git push dokku main:master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enumerating objects: 331, done.
Counting objects: 100% (331/331), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (326/326), done.
Writing objects: 100% (331/331), 1.18 MiB | 2.24 MiB/s, done.
Total 331 (delta 71), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (71/71), done.
remote: -----> Cleaning up...
remote: -----> Building app from herokuish
remote: -----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
remote:        -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in Pipfile.lock
remote: cp: cannot stat '/tmp/build/requirements.txt': No such file or directory
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.11
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2020.11.15
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (ce16c9)...
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        130 static files copied to '/tmp/build/staticfiles', 12 unmodified.
remote:
remote:        -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
remote: -----> Releasing app...
remote: -----> Checking for predeploy task
remote:        No predeploy task found, skipping
remote: -----> Checking for release task
remote: -----> Executing release task from Procfile: python manage.py migrate --noinput
remote: =====> Start of app release task (f02af62b3) output
remote:        success
remote:        Operations to perform:
remote:          Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites
remote:        Running migrations:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
remote:            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:        psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "accounts_customuser" does not exist
remote:        The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
remote:            res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
remote:            post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
remote:            state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
remote:            state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 230, in apply_migration
remote:            migration_recorded = True
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 118, in __exit__
remote:            self.execute(sql)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
remote:            cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
remote:            return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
remote:            return executor(sql, params, many, context)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
remote:            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
remote:            raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
remote:            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:        django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_customuser" does not exist
remote:          Applying account.0001_initial...
remote: =====> End of app release task (f02af62b3) output
remote:  !     Execution of release task failed: python manage.py migrate --noinput
remote: 2021/08/20 08:28:22 exit status 1
remote:  !     exit status 1
remote: 2021/08/20 08:28:22 exit status 1
remote: 2021/08/20 08:28:22 exit status 1
remote: 2021/08/20 08:28:22 exit status 1
To myIP:app
 ! [remote rejected] main -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

**accounts/models.py**

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**gradebook/models.py** for an example of how I use the CustomUser / AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
class Course(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I have thought about trying to run `python manage.py migrate --fake` but I don't know what the consequences of that might be.

Comment: Does the flow include `python manage.py makemigrations`? and then running the migrate? The error that you facing, is because.. one of your migrations depends on table `accounts_customuser` but it seems that it's not created in your database. So you would need that table to be created in the database.

Comment: I now think this is related to some problems I've had with django-allauth and dokku. I haven't had time to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with postgresql. The problem is that the table user does not exist a remedial to that is to apply python manage.py makemigrations app_name for all the apps in your project then python manage.py migrate.